Any hopes of reviving a little potted lavender
I received a small potted lavender that traveled overnight packed in a suitcase. It was healthy and green with nice blooms when bought, but when I opened it the little pot was swimming in maybe a litre of water in the packaging, some of the soft branches had broken and the plant was a little squished. I slipped it out of the pot and squeezed out the excess water gently without disturbing the root ball. There were no broken or rotting roots as far as I could see. The roots were hair like rather than proper roots.  Then planted it in a slightly bigger pot with perlite, loose sandy soil and cocopeat. I also kept it in filtered sunlight for a day or two to help it recover.
Sadly, it just kept getting worse. Now all the little branches are dried out and all the leaves are shrivelled up and brown. Not a single green leaf remains. I do give it plenty of bright sunlight but it looks dead. In desperation I even took it out of the pot to see if the roots were dead too, but they look ok I think. Not dried out I mean. I haven't overwatered it but since it is very hot where I live I did it give a cup of water every third day. I even moved it in the peak of the day to a filtered sunny spot to prevent burn.
Have you ever known a potted lavender to come back from the dead after this point? Is there anything else I can do to help it survive and come back to life?

Is it your habit to repot plants instead of giving them time to acclimate? Lavender is not a wet soil plant.

I couldn't help it. It arrived swimming in what was essentially a bag of water. It came right out of the pot it was in, soil and all, so I just put it into a slightly bigger pot. From that point on it was all downhill. I'm kicking myself for not taking a few cuttings while it was in good shape.

I would try a product called Superthrive, you can typically buy it at any type of garden center, it’s a natural fertilizer, you probably only need a drop of it
For 1 gallon of water
